# Matlab figure print with no axes box

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to print a figure with the mapping toolbox. 
When I print my figure, it always shows a black axes box, although it is not visible in the Matlab figure itself.

This code reproduces the problem:

```
f = figure;
f.Position = [f.Position(1:2) 765 421];
ax = axesm('MapProjection','robinson',...
    'MapLatLimit',[-90 90],'MapLonLimit',[-180 180],....
    'Frame','on','Grid','on');
ax.XColor = 'w';
ax.YColor = 'w';
tightmap

print('test','-dpng','-r150')
```

This is my test.png file with the black axes box:
[image: test.png file]

This is a screenshot from my Matlab figure:
[image: screenshot]

**EDIT:** adding a `box off` removed the top and right line
**EDIT2:** adding a `ax.Visible = false;` worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Adding an `ax.Visible = false;` did it